# Errors searching an arraylist

Tags: arrays, search, arraylist

I've got my working program that creates an array of address, and then searches them.

But my search only looks at the second entry (at index 1) How do I get my search to look through all the entries instead of just the second?

Feel free to ask if I haven't posted enough details!

```
    public static void main(String[] args)          //start method main
    {
    ArrayList<SJAddressBook> SJ = new ArrayList<SJAddressBook>();
    SJAddressBook aBook = null;
    for (int count =0;count <3;count ++)
    {

    aBook = new SJAddressBook();
    SJ.add(aBook.addEntry());
    System.out.println();
    }
    int foundIndex = aBook.search(SJ);          //execute search
    System.out.println();
    if (foundIndex > -1)
        SJ.get(foundIndex).display();
    else
        System.out.println("No Entry Found!");
```

And my search

```
    int search(List<SJAddressBook> addressBook)             
    {
    Scanner entry = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println(" Search Menu;\n 1. First Name \n 2. Last Name \n 3. Street Address \n 4. City, State \n 5. Zip Code ");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Please enter Field to Search: ");
    String menu = entry.next();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Please enter Value to Search: ");
    String value = entry.next();
    int index = 0;
    for (SJAddressBook address : addressBook)           //recieve ArrayList as argument
    {
        switch (index)                                  //intitialze switch
        {
            case 1:
            if (address.getFirstName().equalsIgnoreCase(value))
                return index;
                break;
            case 2:
            if (address.getLastName().equalsIgnoreCase(value))
                return index;
                break;
            case 3:
            if (address.getStreetAddress().equalsIgnoreCase(value))
                return index;
                break;
            case 4:
            if (address.getCityState().equalsIgnoreCase(value))
                return index;
                break;
            case 5:
            if (address.getZipCode().equalsIgnoreCase(value))
                return index;
                break;
        }                                               //end switch

        index++;

    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your function search tries to find the book which matches the user input in some of it's fields, if that's right, why are you using the switch? you can simplify the code by just checking the fields:

```
int search(List<SJAddressBook> addressBook) {
    Scanner entry = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out
            .println(" Search Menu;\n 1. First Name \n 2. Last Name \n 3. Street Address \n 4. City, State \n 5. Zip Code ");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Please enter Field to Search: ");
    String menu = entry.next();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Please enter Value to Search: ");
    String value = entry.next();
    int index = 0;
    for (SJAddressBook address : addressBook) // recieve ArrayList as
                                                // argument
        if (address.getFirstName().equalsIgnoreCase(value) || 
                address.getLastName().equalsIgnoreCase(value) || 
                address.getStreetAddress().equalsIgnoreCase(value) || 
                address.getCityState().equalsIgnoreCase(value) || 
                address.getZipCode().equalsIgnoreCase(value)){
                return index;
        }
        index ++;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

---

**EDIT** 
Your function with switch (which is not usefull here, btw):

```
int search(List<SJAddressBook> addressBook) {
    Scanner entry = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out
            .println(" Search Menu;\n 1. First Name \n 2. Last Name \n 3. Street Address \n 4. City, State \n 5. Zip Code ");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Please enter Field to Search: ");
    String menu = entry.next();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Please enter Value to Search: ");
    String value = entry.next();
    int index = 0;
    for (SJAddressBook address : addressBook) // recieve ArrayList as
        for(int i =0 ; i <= 5; i++){

          switch (index)                                  //intitialze switch
            {
                case 1:
                if (address.getFirstName().equalsIgnoreCase(value))
                    return index;
                    break;
                case 2:
                if (address.getLastName().equalsIgnoreCase(value))
                    return index;
                    break;
                case 3:
                if (address.getStreetAddress().equalsIgnoreCase(value))
                    return index;
                    break;
                case 4:
                if (address.getCityState().equalsIgnoreCase(value))
                    return index;
                    break;
                case 5:
                if (address.getZipCode().equalsIgnoreCase(value))
                    return index;
                    break;
            }   
        }

        index ++;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: A switch is one of the requirements so I had to add it.

Comment: Edited with your requirements